# Is near light speed travel possible? Likely?

Tags: speed-of-light, space, interstellar-travel

I was contemplating the possibility of sending an interstellar probe that can produce results in a reasonable time frame.

For such a mission to be realistic, the spacecraft would have to travel at some (significant) fraction of the speed of light. I calculated that at 0.5c, it would take 14PJ of energy per kilogram. If we assume 500kg probe, that will require 7000PJ of energy.

According to my research, that's about 2000 terrawatts, about half of the yearly electric consumption in the US.
Obviously this is enormous, but given that we can somehow provide constant trust without significantly increasing the spacecraft's weight:

**Is there any fundamental reason that I'm missing that would make near light speed travel not possible?**

**Is there any fundamental reason that would make near light speed travel extremely unpractical/unlikely?**

Edit:
I'm not asking about engineering reasons, but fundamental physics.

Comment: how to drive so fast?

Comment: The largest man-made nuclear bomb weighed 27,000kg (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tsar_Bomba)  Unless you're planning to set them all off in the same instant, then the energy from the first one will be spent accelerating the probe plus all of the other bombs.  Google for "relativistic rocket equation"

Comment: Purely engineering reasons. The same reasons why we can't have space elevators, terraforming, transatlantic bridges or Dyson spheres.

Comment: Also, when comparing the kinetic energy of your probe to the energy produced by nuclear weapons, consider that those are two very different things. Most of the energy released by the Tsar Bomba (if you exploded it out in space) would consist of an isotropic flash of gamma rays.  It's unlikely that you could convert _all_ of that into kinetic energy of your probe.

Comment: Also, what good is it if your probe flashes past the target star system at 0.5c?  If it's going to collect any meaningful data, you'll have to slow it down.  Again, consult that rocket equation.  Having to slow it down doesn't mean double the size of the rocket:  The payload of the rocket that gets everything _up_ to travel speed is the entire rocket that's going to brake the science package back down to normal speed.

Comment: @jameslarge The probe would slow down, it's mentioned in the question. The nuclear equivalency is just to get a feel of how much energy is needed. I'm suggesting to use nuclear weapons as a mean of propulsion, but at least we can see that the energy requirements are somewhat within our means as a specie.

Comment: it;s a cool topic, and it surely has received milliosn of hours of study by scientists, and there are many pages on the subject online, and probably technical terms... hum.. let me see... serchy searchy... https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interstellar_travel

Comment: how do you expect to drive so fast ? the collision mean time depends of the speed, as usual

Comment: @ufomorace I did search but I wanted the answer to be a bit more vigorous; sometimes it's hard if a Wikipedia article is based on solid science or on a science fiction novel. That's why I ran the calculations myself and was surprised to find that the energy required is within our reach. Since my physics is fairly rudimentary I though maybe I'm missing something...

Comment: One can actually travel quite comfortably with exactly the speed of light, just not in form of baryonic matter. All attempts to manufacture something like a near light speed drive are exceedingly poorly reasoned engineering solutions to the problem of interstellar travel. No sensible engineer with a modicum of physics knowledge will ever propose such a scheme.

Comment: Well to some observers, we *are* travelling arbitrarily close to the speed of light.

Comment: OK, and I'm using the Tsar Bomba as an example of how much a device that can produce that much energy might weigh.  Unless the device delivers _all_ the energy in an instant (e.g., like an exploding nuclear bomb), then your "rocket" is going to have to carry the device and its fuel along for the ride.  Like I said, Google for 'relativistic rocket' to get a clear picture of how to calculate the real requirements for energy and reaction mass.

Comment: @jameslarge I removed the reference to the nuclear example. Can we now stop talking about it?

Answer (score 1):

There is a fundamental reason why it might be very, very difficult (not even mentioning the engineering). As you start approaching the speed of light, it becomes harder and harder to accelerate. At 0.5c, this would definitely become a factor. Accelerating from 1%c to 2%c is much easier than accelerating from 50%c to 51%.

Answer (score 1):

Research the average atoms of gas and possible dust particles per cubic meter in deep space and the kinetic impact damage of traveling at .5c through that.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://physics.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://physics.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/397882)

Answer (score 0):

Well fundamnetal physics is pretty solid  here, which explicitly says that $$F=\dfrac{dp}{dt}$$
$$p=\gamma(v) m_0v$$
$$\gamma(v)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-\frac{v^2}{c^2}}}$$
$m_0$ is invariant mass.

So theoretically a spacecraft can accelerate upto any $v<c$ in accordance with the laws. The most prime difficulty is only engineering issues like:

1. Energy source must be huge, reliable, safe, and easy to extract.
2. Energy density/efficiency of fuel or whatever propulsion system.
3. Spacecraft materials must sustain such massive acceleration along with *i guess occupants?*
4. Cost of the spacecraft.
5. Interstellar rocks, asteroids, rogue planets?

Currently no such technology exists, neither nuclear or conventional.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, but what fraction are you talking about?
The most realistic albeit ludicrous idea is using sails to catch nuclear explosions. But achieving only 0.33% lightspeed.

Antimatter catalyzed propulsion assuming sufficient quantities of antimatter can be obtained offer exhaust velocities of .94c which may propel a spaceship to minimum of 0.05 to .25c given enough acceleration time.

Answer (score 0):

There's no fundamental physical reason. Remember that speed is relative: going with 0.01c according to one frame means going with 0.91c according to another.

Answer (score 0):

For anything with mass, it would be quite difficult since the speed of light is a limit that cannot be surpassed. On Earth, the  The Large Hadron Collider has successfully accelerated protons very close to the speed of light (because the photons have so little mass). For objects without mass (a light spot, for example), it IS possible.

Comment: Welcome to PSE! "Photons" in the brackets sould be "protons" as well.